# AWS EKS with Fargate send logs to logstash

Tags: logstash, amazon-eks, fluent-bit, aws-fargate

Good afternoon.
I need to collect application logs in an eks cluster using fargate, in a node group environment I use a fluentbit running with daemon set to collect this and send it to a logstash. But as fargate doesn't support the set daemon, I'm trying some alternatives for that, without using AWS elastic, because we need to send the collections to a logstash.
Has anyone done something like this using these products?

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have the config using Filebeat to send logs to Logstash, thus you can use FileBeat as the sidecar to do the same. If you would like to stick with FluentBit (NOT the AWS Fluentbit provided by Fargate), you can leverage on the [HTTP plugin](https://docs.fluentbit.io/tutorials/ship_to/logstash) of OSS FluentBit and Logstash.

Comment: Setting it up as a sidecar I can't bind the volumes to collect the logs in /var/containers/*.log.
I saw that fargate has a native fluentbit, but I couldn't use it with the output name HTTP, to send it to logstash.

Comment: You need to create an emptyDir volume where both the app. and sidecar containers can access (volumeMounts). Your app. then write log to this location and the logs are pick up by the sidecar; send to Logstash using HTTP plugin.

Comment: is there some example @gohm'c